# Seeking Open Source alternatives to ArcGIS Aggregate and Extract Value to Points?

Tags: qgis, postgis, open-source-gis, spatial-analysis

I am looking for some kind of Open source GIS library which can perform spatial analytic functions same as ArcGIS.

My use case is : I am processing GeoTIFF file provided by USGS and performing Aggregate and Extract Values to Points functions from ArcGIS. Once I have result in GeoDatabase I create Text File out of that, that's all I do. Instead of using Aggregate and Extract Value to Points function from ArcGIS I want to use some open source.

Any thought?

Comment: What's the geodatabase good for? Are you ok with directly creating the text file?

Comment: Actually I am performing two spatial analytic operations like "Aggregate" and "Extract Values to Points" functions from ArcGIS. Thats the main concern.

Comment: In what kind of language are you coding? I assume python. Then you could use ogr, shapely and even the pyqgis libraries. Beware of license issues if you want to sell your product

Comment: @Curlew I am planning you use Java as language, but I am also comfortable with the python as well. Library that you have mentioned above does it has support for the Aggregate and Extract Value to Points functions like we have in ArcGIS?

Comment: Just note that QGIS + Java is not really a feasible combination since QGIS is from the C++ tribe. There are open source GIS based on Java that might be better suited.

Answer (score 2):

1. Extracting values at points:
   In GRASS you can use [v.sample](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.sample.html) and can acces this through QGIS.  Alternatively you can use the Point Sampling plugin (Plugins->Fetch Python Plugins).
2. Aggregate:
   GRASS has many raster functions which will allow you to achieve what you want, though there isn't a directly analogous one to aggregate.  Which one you choose will rather depend on how you want to aggregate your data.  Alternatively, you could use [GDAL_grid](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) to interpolate from your old raster to a new raster.

Comment: Generally in ArcGIS Aggregate functions can directly accepts input as Geo TIFF files as raster and it creates output raster (could be the shape files) whereas in case of other open source like GRASS or GDAL or QGIS will I be able to provide input as Geo TIFF file or I have to convert them in some other format?

Comment: Yes.  GDAL reads a vast number of different types of raster data and GeoTiff is one of the formats.  If you use Grass through the Sextant plugin in QGIS, it can also read GeoTiff directly.

Comment: Thank you , your response is so useful for me and it has given new direction.

Comment: :Thank you , your response is so useful for me and it has given new direction to me. I am looking at how to install GRASS and it has various type of installation guide I am referring http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Installation_Guide to install on my ubuntu machine and there is also other one is for compile and install as well http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install. out of this with which one I should go ahead or is there any other link which has installation step as well as some testing command using that I can confirm the correct installation?

Comment: :Even If I install base GRASS I can install other plugins anytime right like  GDAL and Sextant plugin in QGIS?

Comment: I use Windows so I don't want to mislead you with the installation.  I know there are a number of questions about installing QGIS on Ubuntu on this forum which may help.  However, on Windows, although occasional problems can arise, usually you are safe enough installing the components separately. I assume it is similar for Ubuntu.